# Bootstrap: How to have fixed navigation AND autohide working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, hide, navbar, sticky

I have a fixed nav-bar:

```
<div class="container-fluid topsearch" id="nav">
<!-- content for top search here --> 
</div>
```

JS Code:

```
/* fixed nav topbar */
$('#nav').affix({
      offset: {
        top: $('.topsearch').height()
      }
});
```

Which works but:

1. The navigation bar is underneath another topmenu, so its not directly a sticky, it sticks until you pass by the navbar (which is good). But when you scrolldown the content underneath the navbar jumps up X pixels (X = height of navbar) so its under the navbar. How do it fix this?
2. I want to use http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-autohidingnavbar/ for this navbar, but it doesnt seem to work with the affix method. Anyone got a fix?